# How to set form input as a variable in a Json printing php file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have two php files, file A and file B that get data from the same database.  File A displays the data in a paragraph on the site while File B is used by AJAX to display data in a graph created with `graph.js`. Both files do their job, except.

In both files I have a variable called `$employeeNumber` which is the name of an input field in a form used by the user to input whichever employee number they would like to view the data of. File A allows me to use 
`$employeeNumber = $_POST["employeeNumber"];` to get the input and displays data accurately but File B won't allow me to use `$_POST[]`, `$_REQUEST[]`, or `$_GET[]`. Instead it forces me to hardcode the unique number. This is not desired.

File B is meant to get the input entered into the form, and update the graph with the data relating to the employee number entered.

I used echo `$row["empnumber"];` for File A to display the data and for File B I used `print json_encode($data);` Could this be where I went wrong?

File B (Doesn't update graph unless I hardcode `employeeNum`)

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydb";




//BELOW IS WHERE THE ISSUE LIES.
//WHEN I HARDCODE THE UNIQUE NUMBER LIKE THIS, THE GRAPH UPDATES ACCORDINGLY. WITH ACCURATE DATA FROM THE EMPLOYEE THAT THE UNIQUE NUMBER BELONGS TO.

$employeeNum = 8020;


//THIS (BELOW) I ANTICIPATED WOULD GET THE EMPLOYEE NUMBER FROM THE USERS INPUT IN THE FORM WHICH I HAVE NOW INCLUDED BUT IT PRODUCES AN ERROR. 

$employeeNum = $_POST["employeeNum"]; //this is line 9

//HERE IS THE ERROR WHEN I OPEN THE Graphdata.php FILE

<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: employeeNum in <b>C:\wamp64\www\Graphdata.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>C:\wamp64\www\Graphdata.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function close() on bool in C:\wamp64\www\Graphdata.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\wamp64\www\Graphdata.php</b> on line <b>26</b><br />




//Connect to database
$dbconnect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//If failed to connect
if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    die("Database connection error".mysqli_connect_error());
}
//Create query
$sql = "SELECT Mathematics, English, Afrikaans, Geography, Physics, History, Life_Orientation FROM studentresults WHERE employeeNumber = $employeeNum";

//Run query
$result = $dbconnect->query($sql);

//Produce result
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row){ //THIS IS LINE 22
    $data[] = $row;
}

$result -> close();

$dbconnect -> close();

//Print the result
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

File A (Works fine)

```
<?php 

//connecting to database
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "mydb";
    $employeeNum = $_POST["employeeNum"];

    $connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//checking connection

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die ("Database connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
    } 

// Query the database
        $sql = "SELECT Salary FROM myEmployees WHERE employeeNumber = $employeeNum";

        $result = $connect->query($sql);

//print out result
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row["English"];
    }

$result -> close();
?>
```

Here's the AJAX code making the request

```
$.ajax({

//Graphdata.php is the name of FILE B

    url: "http://localhost/Graphdata.php",
    type: "GET",
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);

        var Salary = [];
        var timeWorked = [];
        var Age = [];
        var userid = [];

        for(var i in data){

            userid.push("UserID " + data[i].userid);
            Salary.push(data[i].Salary);
            Age.push(data[i].Age);
            timeWorked.push(data[i].timeWorked);


        }
//Create the graph
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
```

Here is the form code.

```
<form action="Graphdata.php" method="post">
    <p class="name">Username</p>
<input class="inp1" type="text" name="name">
    <p class="password">Password</p>
<input class="inp2" type="password" name="email">
    <p class="employeeid">Employee ID</p>
<input id = "employeeNum" class="inp3" type="int" name="employeeNum">
```

Comment: Please show to AJAX call in your client side code that is making the request.  I suspect you are not including the `employeeNum` or are using a slightly different name.

Comment: or you can look in DevTools in the Network tab to see what the body of the outgoing request looks like.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Both those scripts use variables `$employeeNum` and `$studentid` that appear to come from KNOWHERE? Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I have corrected the above code the variables come from here: "In both files I have a variable called $employeeNumber which is the name of an input field in a form used by the user to input whichever employee number they would like to view the data of." I thought this would make it obvious that the variable $employeeNum comes from the input name in the form. $studentID was an error. It has been corrected. sorry about that. it isn't relevant.

Comment: @BizzyBob AJAX code has been added, please revise. Thanks.

Comment: @RiggsFolly As for security, I will definitely handle that once I've solved this. Unless it fixes my problem then please let me know so I can get right on it.

Comment: AGAIN! There is so much ___that is relevant___ missing from your code. ___Please rememebr we are NOT Clairvoyant___ I fyou want us to help you, you have to help us!!!

Comment: @Riggs Please calm down. I am not a pro at this and not a full beginner as well. There are still some code practices I am yet to wrap my head around. I am doing my best in explaining my problem as best as I can. I have included all three files, except the html file which consists of the form. As far as I am aware this is the only code that is missing apart from the completion of the AJAX code which creates the graph. I left that out on purpose as everything there works fine and has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: @Riggs At this point I am absolutely clueless as to what could be missing. The security you spoke of earlier is what I will be looking into as soon as this small adjustment is made to my code. I just need a way to update the graph based on data specific to the unique number entered by the user in the form. If you'd like me to include the form as well I will but I am certain that all (names of variables and ID's) is in order as the code wouldn't run in the first place if they weren't.

Comment: Please note changes made to the question. Thanks again for the attempts. I really am trying to make this easy for everyone. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call via AJAX, you are not passing any data along to the back end.

Further, when you use `method=GET`, the `$_POST` array will be empty.

Change your method to `POST`, and include the data like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/Graphdata.php",
  data: {employeeNum: someValue}
  ...
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I get what it was meant to do though it still doesn't read the form data entered. I can include the form contained in the html file if this might help. Also, thanks for the attempt BizzyBob.

Comment: Look in the dev tools of the browser in the Network tab of your XHR request and see what the 'Request Payload' looks like.  I think your data isn't present, or is in a different shape than you expect. [sample screenshot](https://imgur.com/ksHzTYY)